# How to keep track of images in an HTML File(insertion and Deletion)

Tags: html

I have a content editable HTML File, an Editor.
Whenever I insert an image into the editor or remove one from the editor, I want to show an alert.
How can I do this? Any event I have to handle. I can keep track of inserting the image, but how do I keep track of removed images?
I want to calculate the total size of images in my editor - the size of preloaded images (if any) + inserted image size, as well as the total number of images.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function InsertImage() {
      var imagePath = "D:/\images/\Desert.jpg";
        var imageInfo = "<img src='" + imagePath + " ' width='200' height='200'>";
        document.execCommand('InsertHTML',false,imageInfo); 
     }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>    
    <input type="submit" value="Image"  onClick="InsertImage()" />
    <div id="EditBox" contentEditable="true"  
            style="border: solid 1px red; width: 600px; height: 300px; 
            overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll;">
            </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make addition or removal through a function of your own and show an alert in that function.